# ¿Cómo conectar Visual Studio Code a mi contenedor?

Tags: nodejs, visual-studio, vscode, docker, docker-compose

colegas.

Acabo de instalar Debian 12 en mi PC para trabajar; también uso Visual Studio Code y Docker. En el proyecto de mi empresa, usamos [ESLint](https://eslint.org/), [Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html) y [Husky](https://typicode.github.io/husky/). El problema, es que estoy usando mi entorno de desarrollo con Docker y por ende, las librerías que me permiten usar lo anterior, no son utilizadas por mi Visual Studio Code.

Este es mi *'./0.Project_info/Dockerfile' (que es el que uso para mi entorno de desarrollo local)*:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --update nodejs npm

COPY ["package.json","package-lock.json","/usr/src/"]

WORKDIR /usr/src

RUN npm ci

COPY [".","/usr/src/"]

WORKDIR /usr/src
```

Este es mi *'./docker-compose.yml'*:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    container_name: dasboard_api
    image: dasboard_api:1.0.0
    build: .
    command: npm run start
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src
      - /usr/src/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
    networks:
      - dasboard_api

networks:
  dasboard_api:
```

Este es mi *'./docker-compose.override.yml' (que es el que uso para mi local)*:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./0.Project_info/Dockerfile
    command: 'npm run dev'
```

Esta es la configuración de mi Visual Studio Code:

```
{
    "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Sublime Monokai",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "[javascript]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
  "eslint.options": {
    "configFile": "/ruta/en/el/contenedor/.eslintrc.js"
  },
  "eslint.nodePath": "/ruta/en/el/contenedor/node_modules"
}
```

Y por último, este es mi *'package.json'*:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Eliminado por seguridad",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx only-allow npm",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "format:check": "prettier --check \"{controllers,services,docs,helpers,middlewares,routes}/**/*.js\"",
    "format:write": "prettier --write \"{controllers,services,docs,helpers,middlewares,routes}/**/*.js\"",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:check": "eslint \"{controllers,services,docs,helpers,middlewares,routes}/**/*.js\"",
    "lint:fix": "eslint \"{controllers,services,docs,helpers,middlewares,routes}/**/*.js\" --fix",
    "docker:build:dev": "docker-compose -p dash_dev build && docker-compose -p dash_dev down && docker-compose -p dash_dev up -d",
    "docker:build:prod": "docker-compose -p dash_prod build && docker-compose -p dash_prod down && docker-compose -p dash_prod up -d",
    "docker:restart:dev": "docker-compose -p dash_dev restart",
    "docker:restart:prod": "docker-compose -p dash_prod restart"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*": "prettier --write --ignore-unknown"
  },
  "author": "Eliminado por seguridad",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.445.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bottleneck": "^2.19.5",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "debug": "^4.3.4",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.12.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.2",
    "pcloud-sdk-js": "^1.4.3",
    "qs": "^6.7.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.2",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.5.0",
    "vimeo": "^2.3.1",
    "written-number": "^0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "^15.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "sequelize-auto": "^0.8.3"
  }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcionen los demás plugins? A continuación, describiré el comportamiento que tenía en Windows y no usaba Docker:

- Cuando había una variable sin usar, mostraba un error en el mismo editor.
- Al guardar, o formatear manualmente el código, lo acomodaba según las reglas.
- Al hacer commit,husky realiza una serie de pre-commits.

Comment: Se supone que hay una extensión oficial de docker que te permite "adjuntar" tu visual code a un contenedor corriendose. Básicamente lo que hace es abrir una nueva ventana "remota" y conectarse al contenedor. De ahí, necesitas habilitar las extensiones de vs code en ese "remoto" para que funcionen.